# What command can let a player sleep in the morning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any command that can let a player sleep in the morning? If so, what is the command and how is it used?

Comment: Do you want ever lasting night? or just allowing players to move their spawn point during the day?

Comment: As Arperum queried, are you asking for a no daylight cycle?

Comment: Have you tried changing the time?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If they sleep during the day, does it set it to night?

Comment: Why was the question put on hold? The question was clear and in plain English. The answer is no/none.

Comment: @Bizorke I think it's because there are multiple interpretations for what the OP wants, but you're right: there is an answer to the question literally as posed, and it's no.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.8, there is no command (or other method) in vanilla Minecraft to allow players to sleep in the morning or during the day. But depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, there may be other options.

If you want to fast-forward time, use the /time command. To add 8 hours to the clock use:

`/time add 8000`

To set the time to dawn (this will allow you to sleep in a bed) use:

`/time set 13000`

You could even make a command block programmed with `time add 100` execute multiple times in order to create the illusion that time is passing by faster. Lots of ways to get creative, but unfortunately there aren't too many tools for you to use.